# Parsing JSON in Objective C (iOS)

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

I have a problem parsing JSON string in Objective C:
My JSON:

```
{"messages":[{"nick":"Tim","message":"Hallo","time":"06.07.2012 13:26:41"}]}
```

My Objective C Code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"..URL.."];
NSArray *messages = [data objectForKey:@"messages"];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                           JSONObjectWithData:messages
                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                        error:&error];
NSString *nick = [json objectForKey:@"nick"];
NSString *message = [json objectForKey:@"message"];
```

But this doesn´t work and I don´t know what to do!

Comment: Think you mixed up your code a bit there. You are calling `objectForKey:` on the `NSData` object.

Comment: Don't actually see a question in there. When you say "doesn't work", what do you mean? Is there an error? Incorrect results? What have you tried? Gotta give us more if you want help.

Comment: I need NSString instead of NSData or what???

Comment: You are calling `objectForKey:` on the `NSData` before you use `NSJSONSerialization`. I'd be surprised if `messages` in this case was anything but `nil`. Furthermore, ahwulf's answer is correct once that code is flipped around.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is a dictionary of arrays of dictionaries, i.e. {[{}]}

```
NSArray *messages = [json objectForKey:@"messages"];
NSString* nick = [[messages objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"nick"]
```